# grunt-contrib-concat - How to include concatenated path in separator?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Given this simple setup:

```
concat: {
        options: {
            stripBanners: false,
            separator: '\n/* path to js file */\n'
        },
        dist: {
            src: ['js/*.js'],
            dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>-concat.js'
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to dynamically include the concatenated path in each separator?

The ideal concatenated file should be:

```
/* js/file1.js */
var someFunction = function(){

}

/* js/file2.js */
var anotherFunction = function(){
}
```

I'm new to Grunt, any ideas appreciated.

Thanks,

Seb.

Answer (score 1):

in the process options you can put of this manner

```
process: function(src, filepath) {
        console.log('// Source: ' + filepath + '\n'); ;
        return '// Source: ' + filepath + '\n'+src;
      }
```